# AndroidStudo3.1 bug ? Cause application Crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I updated AS to 3.1, but there was a serious bug. Call `onBackPressed()` method of all activities that contains `EditText` will lead

**StackOverFlow Error** ,Only appeared below Android 6.0 devices.

[image]

If i removed the EditText or hide the EditText in xml, the bug was gone.

But if i hide the EditText before `onBackPressed()` method, like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        editText.visibility = View.GONE
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

,when i clicked back button
**NullPointerException** occurred

[image]

In short, if an activity contains a EditText, when i finish the activity the application will crash。

> finish: call `onBackPressed()` or `Activity.finish()` or click the Back button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I am also using `onBackPressed()` but I am not getting this issue, I updated my studio to 3.1 too

Comment: Try `editText.setVisiblity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded AS to 3.0. Problem solved. This should be a bug in AS 3.1